# Tangential Acceleration of a pendulum

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

I have looked at previous questions on physics stack exchange and it has been really helpful, but this is my first time posting so I would be grateful for any information anyone can offer.
My question is, if the tangential acceleration of a pendulum equals              -g*sin(theta), then does this mean it is linear for small angles and not sinusiodal. Meaning the graph should look something like my attached image? Here it is going from hanging straight down, up to a max amplitude and then back down to hanging down (half a period).
Thanks in advance!
[image]

Comment: Does this also mean that the tangential acceleration is indepdendent of the mass and the length of the string? So it would be the same for all objects on different lengths of string? Thanks again

Comment: What do you mean by "this"? The small angle approximation is not necessary in order to have acceleration independent of mass and length.

Comment: What is the _x_-axis because it is not values near zero

Comment: Change the plot in Excel to a scatter plot instead of a line plot.

Answer (score 2):

The swing angle obeys the following dynamics

$$\ddot{\theta} = -\tfrac{g}{\ell} \sin \theta $$

and the tangential acceleration component is

$$ \ell \ddot{\theta} = -g\,\sin \theta $$

Using the small angle approximations the above becomes

$$ \ell \ddot{\theta} \approx -g\, \theta $$

As a graph it should through (0,0)

[image: fig1]

The blue line is a sine wave, and orange the linear approximation.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply! My graph is purely based on inputting the value of 'g' and values between 0-15 degree into the gsin(theta) formula. I am trying to compare it to the values obtained by from an accelerometer I have, where the x component of the acceleration from the accelerometer is the tangential acceleration. Is this the correct method? Or would you suggest another way? Thanks

Comment: @Ark4747 it looks like you did a line graph in Excel instead of an XY-scatter plot. That is why it looks like it is and not like a sine wave.  Excel is not using the _x_-axis value, for a line plot. Line plots are only to be used with non-enumerable values for the _x_-axis. Like days of the week, or things with names and not numbers.

Comment: This was really helpful thankyou!